# Keeping random number the same between methods

Tags: java, loops, methods, random

In the following code The first method (generateRandomNumber) generates a random no between 1 and 10. The second method (guessRandomNumber) then allows the user to guess the number. The problem I am having is that when the user guesses the number wrong it generates another random number instead of the inital one. As a result the user could guess and never get it correct even by entering every possible number. Can anyone advise how I would change this.

First method (generating the number):

```
public static int generateRandomNumber() {

    Random random = new Random();
    // Declaring int for random number and defaulting to 0
    int randomNumber = 0;
    // Assigning randomNumber between 1 and 10
    randomNumber = random.nextInt(10);
    randomNumber++;

    return randomNumber;

}// end of generateRandomNumber
```

Second Method (guessing the number):

```
public static void guessRandomNumber() {

        // declare var for user guess and default to zero
        int userGuess = 0;
        boolean validNumber=false;
        boolean correctGuess=false;
do{

    do{
    try{
        validNumber=true;
        // Get user guess (between 1 and 10)
        System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 10...");
        userGuess = scanner.nextInt();
    }catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Sorry invalid entry...");
        //Flush scanner
        scanner.next();
        validNumber=false;
    }
    }while (!validNumber);
        if (userGuess == generateRandomNumber()) {

            System.out.println("Guess correct, well done!");
            correctGuess=true;

        } else {

            System.out.println("Sorry guess Incorrect please try again!");
            correctGuess=false;
        }
}while (!correctGuess);
    }// end ofGuessRandomNumber
```

Attempt:

```
public static void guessRandomNumber() {

        // declare var for user guess and default to zero
        int userGuess = 0;
        boolean validNumber=false;
        boolean correctGuess=false;
        int secretNumber=generateRandomNumber();
do{

    do{
    try{
        validNumber=true;
        // Get user guess (between 1 and 10)
        System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 10...");
        userGuess = scanner.nextInt();
    }catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Sorry invalid entry...");
        //Flush scanner
        scanner.next();
        validNumber=false;
    }
    }while (!validNumber);
        if (userGuess == secretNumber) {

            System.out.println("Guess correct, well done!");
            correctGuess=true;

        } else {

            System.out.println("Sorry guess Incorrect please try again!");
            correctGuess=false;
        }
}while (!correctGuess);
    }// end ofGuessRandomNumber
```

Comment: `int secretNumber = generateRandomNumber();` and reuse `secretNumber` until guessed correctly?

Comment: In which method would I create this?

Comment: At the begginning of `guessRandomNumber()`

Comment: I have did this however the problem now seems that the first method generates a random number and then when the variable in userGuess is created it changed the number again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate the random number first, before the user guesses, and store it in a variable. Then, instead of calling `generateRandomNumber()` in the line

```
if (userGuess == generateRandomNumber())
```

you need to compare it with that variable.

Comment: In which method should I create this variable? I tried this approach earlier but It didnt seem to work!

Comment: Well, you can infer that from my answer. I told you to compare it with the variable on the line `if (userGuess == generateRandomNumber())`. You wouldn't be able to do that if the variable were in `generateRandomNumber` because it would not be visible from that line because it would be in the other method.

Comment: I have did this however the problem now seems that the first method generates a random number and then when the variable is created it changed the number again? Sorry i just dont quite grasp the concept

Comment: Please post your attempt in the question.

Comment: Your code looks correct... I don't understand what the problem is now.

Comment: When you put a method in a Java file, it doesn't automatically get called, unless it's called `public static void main` and it's in the main class of the program. All other methods don't execute until they are called by your code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42251/discussion-between-rni2013-and-robin-green)

Answer (score 1):

You should generate the random number before the first do loop. Keep it in a variable called `correctNumber`, then test that `userGuess == correctNumber`.